# How to build a transaction that is valid for ANY input of an address but with a specific output

Tags: script, sighash

I am trying to achieve a more complex task, as an use-case where a company holds a very popular bitcoin address that has many hundreds of inputs (UTXOs) in related to stocks it issued.

Now, the intention is to build a transaction that all the stock owners can broadcast if and when they decide to. But they should not be able to spend more than their rightful amount. Can `SIGHASH_SINGLE` be used in this case?

Example:
input0, input1, input2, input3, input4 total = 5.001 btc
output0 = 4 btc, output1 = 1 btc, fee = 0.001 btc

where *output0* is the entire amount going back to the same address
*fee* is the fee
and *output1* is the address of the holder that is entitled to withdraw no more than 1 btc.

The goal is to have a transaction that someone can use to withdraw no more than a certain amount and be valid for any inputs of a given address. Also, if different people have the same transaction but with different output1 and output1 amount, would there be any conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

> **if different people have the same transaction but with different output1 and output1 amount, would there be any conflicts?**

Those transactions would all have the same inputs.

A transaction always consumes and destroys all its inputs.

Therefore the first transaction to be broadcast and confirmed would invalidate all the others.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It makes sense, I know, but if SIGHASH_SINGLE is signed this doesn't mean that the signature is valid for ANY input, and just a certain output? I mean, regardless a previous transaction consumes and destroys certain inputs, if the address has more unspent inputs the transaction can be used for those?

Comment: Transactions don't reference addresses. Specifically, inputs and outputs never contain addresses as such. They reference specific UTXOs.  Therefore any reasoning involving addresses can't apply to the processing of transaction inputs.